# Pipe in for loop breaks double quoted variables

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, pipe, environment-variables, double-quotes

Situation: Using batchscript to retrieve certain values from a JSON.
I've got the following batchscript:

```
@ECHO off

ECHO Enter npo.nl program-url :
SET url=
SET /P url=
:: http://www.npo.nl/buitenhof/03-05-2015/VPWON_1232766/POMS_VPRO_850040 for example
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=6 delims=/" %%A IN ("%url%") DO (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%B IN ('curl.exe -s http://e.omroep.nl/metadata/aflevering/%%A ^| jq.exe -R -r -s ".[1+index(\"^(\"): rindex(\"^)\")]"') DO (
        FOR /F "delims=" %%C IN ('ECHO %%B ^| jq.exe -r .start') DO SET ss=%%C
        FOR /F "delims=" %%C IN ('ECHO %%B ^| jq.exe -r .eind') DO SET to=%%C
        FOR /F "delims=" %%C IN ('ECHO %%B ^| jq.exe -r .tijdsduur') DO SET t=%%C
        ECHO Start:    !ss!
        ECHO End:      !to!
        ECHO Duration: !t!
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
```

What does it do?
Upon having entered a npo.nl program-url, the first for-loop strips the url down to the prid:`POMS_VPRO_850040`. In the second for-loop *curl.exe* retrieves the JSON...:

```
parseMetadata({"STATUS":"OK","VERSION":"1.11.12","prid":"VPWON_1232766","titel":"Schuim & As","aflevering_titel":"","info":"Schuim & As met Jelle Brandt Corstius","ratio":"16:9","medium":"tv","gidsdatum":"2015-05-03","tijdsduur":"00:05:27","start":"00:23:13","eind":"00:28:40","url":"","webcast":1,"images":[{"size":"640x480","ratio":"4:3","url":"http:\/\/images.poms.omroep.nl\/image\/sx480\/c640x480\/606030.jpg"},{"size":"720x405","ratio":"16:9","url":"http:\/\/images.poms.omroep.nl\/image\/sx405\/c720x405\/606030.jpg"}],"omroepen":[{"naam":"VPRO"}],"pubopties":["adaptive","h264_bb","h264_sb","h264_std"],"tt888":"ja","serie":{"srid":"VPWON_1232748","serie_titel":"Buitenhof","serie_url":null},"sitestat":{"baseurl":"http:\/\/b.scorecardresearch.com\/p?c1=2&c2=17827132&ns_site=po-totaal","programurl":"uitzendinggemist.publiekeomroep.ondemand.tv.buitenhof.20150503","programurlpost":"category=uitzendinggemist&amp;thema=informatief&amp;po_source=video","baseurl_subtitle":"http:\/\/nl.sitestat.com\/klo\/po\/s","subtitleurl":"uitzendinggemist.publiekeomroep.ondemand.tv.player.tt888.buitenhof","subtitleurlpost":"category=uitzendinggemist&amp;po_source=video&amp;po_sitetype=webonly"},"reclame":"http:\/\/pubads.g.doubleclick.net\/gampad\/ads?_cookie_&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&sz=_sz_&correlator=_correlator_&iu=\/9233\/_site_\/buitenhof&url=_url_&cust_params=genre%3Dinformatief%2Cnieuws%2Factualiteiten%26dur%3D3284%26prid%3DVPWON_1232766%26srid%3DVPWON_1232748%26player%3D_player_","streamSense":{"episode":"buitenhof","program":"buitenhof","station":"nederland_1","sitestatname":"uitzendinggemist.publiekeomroep.ondemand.tv.buitenhof.20150503","sko":"TRUE","sko_dt":"20150503","sko_pr":"buitenhof","sko_stid":"1","sko_ty":"tv.seg","sko_prid":"vpwon1232766","sko_t":"1210","sko_cl":"3284"}})
//epc
```

...and sends it through a pipe to *jq.exe* which removes the non-JSON-data `parseMetadata(` and `) //epc` and leaves the single line intact. This is for 2 reasons: 1) with non-JSON-data present we can't process anything, and 2) for-loops process only 1 line at a time.
The subsequent jq.exe's retrieve values for the specified objects without double quotes.
As long as curl.exe and jq.exe are in the same directory as the batchscript, or in the %path%-variable, this is working all fine:

```
Start:     00:23:13
End:       00:28:40
Duration:  00:05:27
```

Now I want to call curl.exe and jq.exe from another map. One with spaces in it:

```
SET curl="C:\map with spaces\curl.exe"
SET jq="C:\map with spaces\jq.exe"

@ECHO off

ECHO Enter npo.nl program-url :
SET url=
SET /P url=
:: http://www.npo.nl/buitenhof/03-05-2015/VPWON_1232766/POMS_VPRO_850040 for example
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=6 delims=/" %%A IN ("%url%") DO (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%B IN ('%curl% -s http://e.omroep.nl/metadata/aflevering/%%A ^| %jq% -R -r -s ".[1+index(\"^(\"): rindex(\"^)\")]"') DO (
        FOR /F "delims=" %%C IN ('ECHO %%B ^| %jq% -r .start') DO SET ss=%%C
        FOR /F "delims=" %%C IN ('ECHO %%B ^| %jq% -r .eind') DO SET to=%%C
        FOR /F "delims=" %%C IN ('ECHO %%B ^| %jq% -r .tijdsduur') DO SET t=%%C
        ECHO Start:    !ss!
        ECHO End:      !to!
        ECHO Duration: !t!
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
```

For the 2nd for-loop this causes problems:

```
'C:\map' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

While `'ECHO %%X ^| %jq%'` does work, it seems `'%curl% ^| %jq%'` doesn't. So for some reason things go wrong as soon as 2 variables in a pipe are parsed.

Well, no more pipe then:

```
SET curl="C:\map with spaces\curl.exe"
SET jq="C:\map with spaces\jq.exe"

@ECHO off

ECHO Enter npo.nl program-url :
SET url=
SET /P url=
:: http://www.npo.nl/buitenhof/03-05-2015/VPWON_1232766/POMS_VPRO_850040 for example
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=6 delims=/" %%A IN ("%url%") DO (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%B IN ('%curl% -s http://e.omroep.nl/metadata/aflevering/%%A') DO (
        FOR /F "delims=" %%C IN ('ECHO %%B ^| %jq% -R -r -s ".[1+index(\"^(\"): rindex(\"^)\")]"') DO (
            FOR /F "delims=" %%D IN ('ECHO %%C ^| %jq% -r .start') DO SET ss=%%D
            FOR /F "delims=" %%D IN ('ECHO %%C ^| %jq% -r .eind') DO SET to=%%D
            FOR /F "delims=" %%D IN ('ECHO %%C ^| %jq% -r .tijdsduur') DO SET t=%%D
            ECHO Start:    !ss!
            ECHO End:      !to!
            ECHO Duration: !t!
        )
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
```

Now curl.exe and jq.exe each in a for-loop. At first this seems to work fine. The 3 values are echoed, but then things go wrong:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 5

parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 5
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 5
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 5
Start:    00:23:13
End:      00:28:40
Duration: 00:05:27
```

Like I said before; for-loops parse and process only 1 line at a time. The non-JSON-data `//epc` on the 2nd line causes the for-loop to start over, which goes horribly wrong as you can see. That's the reason for the pipe between curl and jq in the code above. To output 1 single line to process. Sadly that didn't work either...sigh.

Of course using temporary files is a last resort when curl and jq are still in a map with spaces in it, but I prefer to use variables, so I'm trying to solve the pipe-issue. I've tried 'usebackq' in the for-loop using backticks around the command instead of single-quotes for instance, but to no avail.
So far I haven't found a solution. Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour and how to solve it?

Comment: This does not seem to be related to `jq` or `curl` in the slightest; rather, it seems to be about escaping the name of the `map with spaces` folder correctly in the batch script. I think it would make sense to remove those tags.

Comment: Are you willing to consider using PowerShell or another scripting language that doesn't require such a mind-bending syntax to correctly parse paths?

Comment: I'd figure other scripting languages can tackle this issue easily, but I prefer to use batch in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [Dave Benham's answer on a related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8202245/2703456) I've found the solution!
It appeared to be a specific FOR /F bug in WinXP, and guess what, here I'm still on WinXP. To fix the main offender, the curl-pipe-jq-for-loop, I had to put `^"` in front of **and** after the entire command. Thus the entire batchscript, which I've also further improved:

```
@ECHO off
CLS

:: NPO JSON-extractor geschreven door Reino Wijnsma, 2015 (reino@degeelebosch.nl)

SET batchname=NPO JSON-extractor
SET version=1.1
TITLE %batchname% %version%

SET curl="C:\map with spaces\curl.exe"
SET jq="C:\map with spaces\jq-1.5rc1.exe"

:Check
IF EXIST %curl% (
    IF EXIST %jq% (
        GOTO Input
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO 'jq.exe' niet gevonden.
        ECHO.
        PAUSE
        GOTO :eof
    )
    GOTO Input
) ELSE (
    ECHO 'curl.exe' niet gevonden.
    ECHO.
    PAUSE
    GOTO :eof
)

:Input
ECHO Voer npo.nl programmalink in :
SET url=
SET /P url=
:: http://www.npo.nl/buitenhof/03-05-2015/VPWON_1232766/POMS_VPRO_850040 bijvoorbeeld
IF "%url%"=="" GOTO :eof

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%A IN ("%url%") DO (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%B IN ('^"%curl% -s http://e.omroep.nl/metadata/aflevering/%%~nxA ^| %jq% -R -r -s ".[1+index(\"(\"): rindex(\"^)\")]"^"') DO (
        ECHO.
        ECHO JSON:
        FOR /F "delims=" %%C IN ('ECHO %%B ^| %jq% .') DO ECHO %%C
        ECHO.
        FOR /F "tokens=1-3" %%C IN ('ECHO %%B ^| %jq% -r "[.tijdsduur,.start,.eind] | @tsv"') DO (
            ECHO Tijdsduur: %%C
            IF NOT "%%D"=="" (
                SET ss=%%D
                SET to=%%E
                SET /A "_ss=((1!ss:~0,2!-100)*3600)+((1!ss:~3,2!-100)*60)+(1!ss:~6,2!-100)"
                SET /A "_to=((1!to:~0,2!-100)*3600)+((1!to:~3,2!-100)*60)+(1!to:~6,2!-100)"
                ECHO Start:     %%D (!_ss!s^)
                ECHO Einde:     %%E (!_to!s^)
            )
        )
    )
)
ECHO.
ENDLOCAL
GOTO Input
```

Important notes for future reference:

```
jq-syntax:           jq -R -r -s  '.[1+index("("):   rindex(")")]'
cmd-shell:           jq -R -r -s  ".[1+index(\"(\"): rindex(\")\")]"
for-loop:           'jq -R -r -s  ".[1+index(\"(\"): rindex(\"^)\")]"'
for-loop (path): '^"%jq% -R -r -s ".[1+index(\"(\"): rindex(\"^)\")]"^"'
```

- For the cmd-shell you have to escape the double quotes with a line-feed `\`.
- While 2 of the closing parenthesis are part of jq's syntax, the 1 between double quotes is not. So when in a for-loop, to prevent this for-loop from closing, you'd have to escape this one with a `^`.
- When jq's executable path is put in a variable with double quotes, to circumvent a WinXP bug, you'd then also have to put the entire command between `^"`, because the parenthesis are now considered special characters! This workaround is compatible with Vista and beyond. (See also [DosTips.com](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=41301#p41301))

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to test it, I suggest to try your batch code as written below:

```
@ECHO off
SET "curl=C:\map with spaces\curl.exe"
SET "jq=C:\map with spaces\jq.exe"
ECHO Enter npo.nl program-url :
SET "url="
SET /P "url="
:: http://www.npo.nl/buitenhof/03-05-2015/VPWON_1232766/POMS_VPRO_850040 for example
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=6 delims=/" %%A IN ("%url%") DO (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%B IN ('"%curl%" -s http://e.omroep.nl/metadata/aflevering/%%A') DO (
        FOR /F "delims=" %%C IN ('ECHO %%B ^| "%jq%" -R -r -s ".[1+index(\"^(\"): rindex(\"^)\")]"') DO (
            FOR /F "delims=" %%D IN ('ECHO %%C ^| "%jq%" -r .start') DO SET "ss=%%D"
            FOR /F "delims=" %%D IN ('ECHO %%C ^| "%jq%" -r .eind') DO SET "to=%%D"
            FOR /F "delims=" %%D IN ('ECHO %%C ^| "%jq%" -r .tijdsduur') DO SET "t=%%D"
            ECHO Start:    !ss!
            ECHO End:      !to!
            ECHO Duration: !t!
        )
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
```

The difference to your code is the position of the double quotes on assigning a string to an environment variable.

The command **set** is usually used with the parameter **variable=value** whereby this entire string is the parameter.

The command

```
SET "curl=C:\map with spaces\curl.exe"
```

puts the entire parameter of command **set** into double quotes. As a result the environment variable `curl` is defined with string `C:\map with spaces\curl.exe` without double quotes assigned to it.

As an extra bonus of using double quotes on entire parameter string of command **set**, usually not visible trailing spaces and tabs at end of command line are now ignored.

But using

```
SET curl="C:\map with spaces\curl.exe"
```

results in a completely different behavior. The entire parameter **variable=value** of command **set** is now not enclosed in double quotes. As a result of the different position of first double quote in the line the command **set** creates now the environment variable `curl` with assigning the string `"C:\map with spaces\curl.exe"` to it with the double quotes and with including perhaps also existing spaces and tabs at end of the command line.

The batch code below copied into a batch file and executed demonstrates the differences:

```
@echo off
set "Var1=String with spaces and "double quotes""   
set Var2="String with spaces and "double quotes""
set Var3="String with spaces and "double quotes" and 3 trailing spaces"   
echo Var1=#%Var1%#
echo Var2=#%Var2%#
echo Var3=#%Var3%#
pause
```

Character `#` on output of the 3 variables is used to display where the assigned strings really start and end.

The output is:

```
Var1=#String with spaces and "double quotes"#
Var2=#"String with spaces and "double quotes""#
Var3=#"String with spaces and "double quotes" and 3 trailing spaces"   #
```

There are 3 trailing spaces at end of line defining `Var1`, but they are ignored as the double quotes enclose the entire parameter string of command **set**.

There are no trailing spaces on line defining `Var2`, but all 4 double quotes are now part of the assigned string and not just the two double quotes around `double quotes` part of the string.

And last the line defining `Var3` has also 3 trailing spaces which are also assigned to the variable which is very often not wanted on command lines referencing the value of the environment variable.

So best is to use always `set "variable=value"` even if whether variable name nor value contains a space. This notation is simply a protection against invisible trailing spaces or tabs being also assigned to the environment variable.

As `curl.exe` with path containing spaces is now assigned to the environment variable `curl` without the double quotes, it is necessary to use the double quotes around the complete string containing `%curl%` which is here simply `"%curl%"`. Same is true for `%jq%` as being not used inside a longer string and therefore always just `"%jq%"` can be used.

One last hint: Debugging of batch files is often quite simple. Changing first line from `@ECHO off` to `@ECHO ON` or removing/commenting first line results in execution of batch file with showing also what is really executed by command line interpreter. The error in code can be often quickly found now by looking on the command lines processed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mofi. I'm aware of commenting `@ECHO off`. I've used it a lot! I understand your plead for the position of double quotes in variables, but I always make sure my variables don't have trailing characters. It's also not the solution, because the for-loop would still startover for `//epc`. The problem was actually a bug in the FOR /F parser. See below.